# Nonce for Trashing Item

Tags: nonce, trash

I have a custom admin page.

On it, I have created a filtered list of the custom post type based on postmeta data.

I have to create a link to delete that post.

I am trying to figure out how to create the link with a nonce.

```
sprintf('<a href="post.php?post=%s&action=%s&_wpnonce=%s" class="link-course-delete">Trash</a>',$item['ID'],'trash',wp_create_nonce(???))
```

I am not sure what value to pass to wp_create_nonce to make it work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer - this contains sample code which helped me resolve the issue.

https://codex.wordpress.org/WordPress_Nonces